# Replace empty / NA Values from data table with other values from the same data table in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, if-statement, na

I would love to replace empty/NA values from a data table with other values that are shown in the variable of the same data table

So I have something like this:

| Country | Nationality | currentLoc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AR | ES | RU |
| empty | empty | ES |
| empty | AR | AR |
| EN | EN | EN |
| EN | ES | ES |

Result should be:

| Country | Nationality | currentLoc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AR | ES | RU |
| ES | empty | ES |
| AR | AR | EN |
| EN | EN | EN |
| EN | ES | ES |

I wrote the following R code:

```
df1$Country[df1$Country== "" | df1$Country=="  "] <- "empty"

df1$Country <-ifelse(df1$Country == "empty", df1$Nationality, ifelse(df1$Nationality == "empty", df1$currentLoc, df1$Country))
```

However not all "empty" cells are replaced in the "Country" Column.

I tried already to specify the empty spaces in the `df1$Country` with `NA`, so I have done like

```
df1$Country[df1$Country== "" | df1$Country=="  "] <- NA

df1$Country <-ifelse(is.na(df1$Country), df1$Nationality, ifelse(is.na(df1$Nationality), df1$currentLoc, df1$Country))
```

That is unfortunately also not working.

Could you help me out in this? I searched for similar questions here, but did not quit get the desired response.

Any help very much appriciated. :)

Cheers

Le1nO

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to relace `"empty"` values in the `Country` variable with the value of the `Nationality` column, and in the case the `Nationality` variable is also `"empty"`, then replace `Country` with the `currentLoc` value.
If this is correct, your first attempt is close to what you want, but you need to fix it a little. `ifelse` take a test, a value if the test is true and a value if the test is false, so:

1. **test**: `df1$Country == "empty"` meaning testing if `Country` is empty
2. **value for true**: If `Country` is empty, means that we need to take `Nationality`, but this variable can also be empty, so we need to check for it with another `ifelse`, something like this: `ifelse(df1$Nationality == "empty", df1$currentLoc, df1$Nationality)` which means, check if nationality is empty and if it is, take `currentLoc`, if not left the `Nationality` value.
3. **value for false**: if `Country` is not empty, then nothing to do, left the country value.

So something like this should work:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  Country = c("AR", "empty", "empty", "EN", "EN"),
  Nationality = c("ES", "empty", "AR", "EN", "ES"),
  currentLoc = c("RU", "ES", "AR", "EN", "ES")
)


df1$Country <- ifelse(
  test = df1$Country == "empty",
  yes = ifelse(df1$Nationality == "empty", df1$currentLoc, df1$Nationality),
  no = df1$Country
)

df1
#>   Country Nationality currentLoc
#> 1      AR          ES         RU
#> 2      ES       empty         ES
#> 3      AR          AR         AR
#> 4      EN          EN         EN
#> 5      EN          ES         ES
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks a lot. This might work. Im wondering, if there is an other way. how is it about, if I define the cells first as `NA_character_` and use `if_else`.  the condition that `if_else` requires should be than something like `if_else(is.na(df1$Country), if_else(is.na(df1$Nationality), d1$currentLoc, d1$Nationality), d1$Country`?

Comment: Yeah, of course. That would work also, and probably easier to read later. I was just using "empty" as it was you used in the question

Answer (score 0):

An approach using the data.table package:

```
library(data.table)    
df1 <- data.table(
      Country     = c("AR", ""  , ""  , "EN", "EN"),
      Nationality = c("ES", ""  , "AR", "EN", "ES"),
      currentLoc  = c("RU", "ES", "AR", "EN", "ES")
    )
```

First step: convert all blanks to NA:

```
df1[df1==""] <- NA
```

Second step: `Country` equals to `Country`, otherwise `Nationality`, otherwise `currentLoc`:

```
> df1 [, Country:=fcoalesce(Country,Nationality, currentLoc)][]
   Country Nationality currentLoc
    <char>      <char>     <char>
1:      AR          ES         RU
2:      ES        <NA>         ES
3:      AR          AR         AR
4:      EN          EN         EN
5:      EN          ES         ES
```

OBS: You may apply a regex for testing for "empty" records (for instance, "", "empty", "   ", etc.) by substituting the instruction `df1[df1==""] <- NA` for:

```
regex_empty <- "^ *$|empty"  # regex that captures multiple spaces and "empty" records
regex_mapping <- df2[, lapply(.SD,function(x)grepl(regex_empty, x, perl = T))] |> as.matrix()
df2[regex_mapping] <- NA
```

This code will make it possible to deal with cases such as df2:

```
> df2 <- data.table(
+   Country     = c("AR", ""     , "empty", "EN", "EN"),
+   Nationality = c("ES", "     ", "AR"   , "EN", "ES"),
+   currentLoc  = c("RU", "ES"   , "AR"   , "EN", "ES")
+ ) 
> 
> regex_empty <- "^ *$|empty"
> regex_mapping <- df2[, lapply(.SD,function(x)grepl(regex_empty, x, perl = T))] |> as.matrix()
> df2[regex_mapping] <- NA
> df2 [, Country:=fcoalesce(Country,Nationality, currentLoc)][]
   Country Nationality currentLoc
    <char>      <char>     <char>
1:      AR          ES         RU
2:      ES        <NA>         ES
3:      AR          AR         AR
4:      EN          EN         EN
5:      EN          ES         ES
> 
> all.equal(df1, df2)
[1] TRUE
```